# SegFault when passing two pointer parameter in a function in C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

**I'm using GCC Compiler 9.3.0 on GNU/Linux Environmental, using C17.**

## I have to remove the code since I can't show that to everyone, please understand.

**If I remove largest_lowest call from main function there is not seg fault if I add that line there is a seg fault (core dumped)**

***SetData is a simple function just to set data only. Nothing more and works perfectly.***

`Error(When compiling)-> expected ‘point **’ but argument is of type ‘point (*)[7]’`

And when I run the program there is a seg fault (core dumped).

Comment: Why do you run that program after your compiler told you that you pass incompatible parameters? The function expects an array of pointers (which decays to pointer to pointer during function call) while you pass a pointer to an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a multi-dimensional array to a function taking pointer-to-pointer. Particularly since in this case, you are intend to pass a single dimension array. Fixes:

`int largest_lowest(point *a[], int len)` - > `point a[]`, and
`largest_lowest(&a, 7);` -> `largest_lowest(a, 7);`

Also, please note that the function-like macro `INIT_POINT_ARRAY` is *horrible practice* and you *must* get rid of it. There is absolutely no reason why you should have a macro there.

Comment: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘point’ int largest_lowest(point a[], int len);

Comment: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
  largest_lowest(a, 7);

Comment: @TusharChaurasia You didn't just simply delete the macro right? You need to take the code that was in the macro and paste it in main().

Comment: Thanks some modification fixed it.

Comment: Can you explain why macro was a bad practice?

Comment: @TusharChaurasia Because it fills no purpose except to making the code harder to read.